# How to get the value of the selected checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a filter function whereby a user can check one or multiple amenities and get the values which will be sent to the database using AJAX.

In this case upon clicking one checkbox I also want to get the values of the other checkboxes if they are checked.

On clicking the `#balcony` input I will get the value of the balcony, also when I click the `#wifi` checkbox I want to get the 'yes' value

How can I achieve this? I have tried the following logic but it doesn't work.

```js
$("#balcony").on('click', function() {
  var balcony = $(this).val();
  var wifi = $("#wifi").prop('checked');
  var parking = $("#parking").prop('checked');
  var generator = $("#generator").prop('checked');

  console.log(wifi);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-title" style="margin:0px; padding:3px;">
    <h5 style="color: black; font-size:18px;">Amenities</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterbalcony" value="yes" id="balcony">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Balcony</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filtergenerator" value="yes" id="generator">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Generator</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterwifi" value="yes" id="wifi">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Wifi</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterparking" value="yes" id="parking">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Parking</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working, but you've only assigned the event handler to the `#balcony` element, so that's why you see that behaviour. It would help to see the expected output, and a clearer description of what happens when you check each box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only checking if the `checkbox` is checked or not, you can either use

`var wifi = $("#wifi").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';`

**or**

`var wifi = $("#wifi:checked").val();`

**Beware that this will return undefined if wifi is not checked**

```js
$("#balcony").on('click', function() {
  var balcony = $(this).val();
  var wifi = $("#wifi").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';
  var wifi2 = $("#wifi:checked").val();
  var parking = $("#parking").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';
  var generator = $("#generator").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';

  console.log(wifi);
  console.log(wifi2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-title" style="margin:0px; padding:3px;">
    <h5 style="color: black; font-size:18px;">Amenities</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterbalcony" value="yes" id="balcony">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Balcony</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filtergenerator" value="yes" id="generator">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Generator</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterwifi" value="yes" id="wifi">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Wifi</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterparking" value="yes" id="parking">
    <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Parking</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way i can get the values without using the #balcony element as an event handler? because the code works well but my brings some confusion because i want on clicking the balcony id or the other inputs i get all their values without depending on one element

Answer (score 1):

You can try below snippet. I have added class to input boxes and just modified event to `change`

```js
$(".filterCheckbox").on('change', function() {
    var balcony = $("#balcony").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    var generator = $("#generator").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    var wifi = $("#wifi").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    var parking = $("#parking").prop('checked') ? 'yes' : 'no';

    console.log('balcony => ' + balcony + ', generator => ' + generator +', wifi => ' + wifi + ', parking => ' + parking);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-title" style="margin:0px; padding:3px;">
        <h5 style="color: black; font-size:18px;">Amenities</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterbalcony" value="yes" class="filterCheckbox" id="balcony">
        <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Balcony</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filtergenerator" value="yes" class="filterCheckbox" id="generator">
        <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Generator</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterwifi" value="yes" class="filterCheckbox" id="wifi">
        <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Wifi</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterparking" value="yes" class="filterCheckbox" id="parking">
        <label for="rentalcat" class="control-label">Parking</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot sir..i have learnt something